# Conflicting action statement in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am getting the following error : `Conflicting action statement in ansible`.

I tried to understand, my code seems to be correct. I declared the name correctly though it gives an error in the task name.

Playbook:

```yaml
---
 - hosts: webhost
   sudo: yes
   connection: ssh

   tasks:
    - name: debuging module
      shell: ps aux
      register: output
      debug: var=output
```

Error message:

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements

The error appears to have been in '/home/test/playbooks/debug.yml': line 7, column 7, but may be present elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be here:
    
       tasks:
        - name: debuging module
          ^ here
```

Answer (score 40):

Here is the problem, you have mixed up two tasks into one:

```yaml
---
- hosts: webhost
  sudo: yes
  connection: ssh

  tasks:
    - name: debuging module
      shell: ps aux
      register: output

    - name: show the value of output
      debug: var=output
```

And out put of the playbook will be like this:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.33.100]

TASK [debuging module] *********************************************************
changed: [192.168.33.100]

TASK [show the value of output] ************************************************
ok: [192.168.33.100] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "ps aux",
        "delta": "0:00:00.004981",
        "end": "2016-06-26 06:25:22.975876",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2016-06-26 06:25:22.970895",
        "stderr": "",
        "stdout": "USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND\nroot         1  0.8  0.2  24432  2380 ?        Ss   06:23   0:00 /sbin/init\nroot         2  0.0  0.0
```

Hope that help you

Comment: thank you for the reply .                                                                                             can you please tell me when to use hyphen and when not to use hyphen for a task, that really confuses me .

Comment: use hyphen at the beginning of each task. does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: yes, it solved my problem . but i just want to know when to use hyphen and when not to use hyphen . becoz i lack clarity , i am getting those errors .

Comment: Can you marked it valid answer, this link will help you to understand https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples